# Integration by parts twice problem with the answer

Tags: integration, solution-verification

I am trying to integrate $\sin(x)e^{x(1-ik)}$ from $-\infty$ to $0$. The answer I am supposed to get is $\dfrac{k^2-2\mathrm{i}k-2}{k^4+4}$ but I get $\dfrac{-1}{1-(1-\mathrm{i}k)^2}$(I have checked and these are not equivalent). I looked at it many times but I cannot find the mistake I will put the working down below:
[image]

Comment: Instead of using IBP, it's a lot easier to put $\sin x = \frac 1{2i}(e^{ix} - e^{-ix})$ and render the expression as the difference of two exponentials.

Comment: @Deepak yeah I figured but I tried this way and I don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: Also have you checked that your answer doesn't simplify to theirs?  The polynomial degrees of your expressions (in k) are compatible such that they could turn out to be equal.

Comment: @JakeMirra I thought about that so I just substituted different values into k but the answers gave different results

Comment: Here's a tip for catching algebra errors - copy your workings onto another piece of paper, making sure to make it very neat and deliberate. As you work through copying down what you previously wrote, you will often catch small errors.

Comment: @K.defaoite hehe I did that at least 3 times ! .. pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second integration by parts you did $ uv + \int{v du} $ when you meant $ uv - \int{v du} $.

Comment: Thanks ! Right in front of my face for so long !